# pgadmin dashboard is gone

Tags: pgadmin-4

The Dashboard option is gone from the menu. Now I can't see the nice graphs anymore.

[image]

What do I need to get it back

I'm using version 4.17?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try File - Preferences - Dashboard within PGAdmin. See if toggling those options will bring it back.

If not, then providing you do not have any customised layout, try File - Reset Layout.

Comment: File - Reset Layout. is don't see this option also

Comment: i reinstalled it again on MAC book pro still same issue strange

Comment: resetting worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the menu and go to 'Add Panel'. You will find 'Dashboard' in the drop down menu. Click on it and the dashboard tab will open.

Comment: for me, it's so bad that I don't see the only object option  and a Browser tab but it's of no use

Answer (score 4):

On pgAdmin4 v6.9 go to

File -> Reset Layout

That's it